# Can I express $(1+x)^{-k} - x^{-k}$, $ x>0 $, $k \in R$ as solely a function of $x^{-k}$?

Tags: polynomials

Can I express $(1+x)^{-k} - x^{-k}$ as solely a function of $x^{-k}$,  $x>0$, $k \in R$? In other words, can the solution be expressed such that the only exponent of $x$ in the solution is $-k$?

Comment: Set $y=x^{-k}$, then your expression is $(1+y^{-1/k})^{-k} - y$.

Comment: Andreas, is it possible to further simply the expression you suggested?

Comment: Not very much. You can have $y(-1 + (1+y^{1/k})^{-k})$ but that doesn't make it much better.